# Creating simple like button

Tags: python, html, django, error-handling

Hi im developping a blog app and i am creating a simple like button for the post idintified by it's pk where the link is located in a form but it ran into an error.

NoReverseMatch at /single_post/8/
Reverse for 'like_post' not found. 'like_post' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

my views.py for the detail view and the like button view

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)

    context = {
        'post': post,
    }
    return render(request, 'news/post_detail.html', context)





def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    post.likes.add(request.user)

    return(HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('single_post', args=[str(pk)] )))
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/', default='img/default.jpg')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    credit = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='daily_posts')
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

in the detail views the form and the link

```
<form action="**{% url 'like_post' post.pk %}**" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit", name="post_id", value="{{ post.id }}">Like</button>
                    </form>
```

and the error i run to everytime i hit like.

```
NoReverseMatch at /single_post/8/
Reverse for 'like_post' not found. 'like_post' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

i cannot identify what seems to be the issue here anyone can help please?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In LikeView, you reverse `'single_post'` but in the form you have `'like_post'`. Perhaps change `'single_post'` in LikeView to `'like_post'`?</strike> **EDIT FOR NAMESPACE**: I believe you need to include the namespace in the form i.e. `{% url 'news:like_post' post.pk %}`

Comment: i did it but it does not work still, what i mean to do is reversing on the post since the like function does not land on another page it only send the like count to the database

Comment: Can you include your code for your URL configurations please?

Comment: Did you set a namespace in your URL configuration i.e. ````app_name````?

Comment: @OthnielLafond I edited my answer. I believe you need to include the namespace in the form.